# python error (error no.32 broke pipe)in playing video in tvml

Tags: apple-tv, tvml

I am trying to play video from tvml script but getting python error no.32 broke pipe and not able to play video.

Script is:

```
<document>
   <stackTemplate>
      <banner>
         <title>Available Action Movies</title>
      </banner>
      <collectionList>
         <shelf>
            <section>
               .....
               .....
               <lockup videoURL="http://localhost:9001/media/video.mp4">
                  <img src="http://localhost:9001/images/movie-1.jpg" width="182" height="274" />
                  <title>Movie</title>
               </lockup>
            </section>
         </shelf>
      </collectionList>
   </stackTemplate>
</document>
```

Getting error:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Dec/2016 14:48:39] "GET /media/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1',
>   55920) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 321, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 334, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 657, in **init**
>       self.finish()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 716, in finish
>       self.wfile.close()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 283, in close
>       self.flush()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 307, in flush
>       self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size]) error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to play mp4  or mov files on Apple tv through TVML app(Client server app) as I read article on [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH12-SW1) that

> All video playback on Apple TV is based on HTTP Live Streaming and
>   FairPlay Streaming. See About HTTP Live Streaming and FairPlay
>   Streaming Overview. For HTTP Live Streaming authoring specifications,
>   see HLS Authoring Specification for Apple TV.

Thou I can play same format file in traditional app using AVPlayer.